# mount: unknown filesystem type '0'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, mount, ntfs

I recently did a fresh install of elementary OS, dual booting with windows 8.1.
After the install was finished, I edited fstab file of eOS so that it would automatically mount a ntfs partition at the address /mnt/Windows.
Later after that I turned off the laptop and when I powered it on later, after choosing elementary OS in grub's options, I get the error "There was an error while mounting filesystem '0'", or something like that.
I proceeded to elementary OS by skipping the error and it appears that ntfs partition was mounted at the address /mnt/Windows and it's fully available to usage from my account in linux.
I opened a terminal and did this:

```
sudo mount -a
```

The result was:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type '0'
```

I got this error after editing fstab file, so the way I mount that partition is the cause. Tried these two ways:

```
UUID=01D01BB10A417E10             /mnt/Windows  ntfs-3g rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   2

UUID=01D01BB10A417E10             /mnt/Windows  ntfs-3g rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

Tried with ntfs instead of ntfs-3g and it's still the same.
Also, I don't get the error "There was an error while mounting filesystem type '0'" if I hibernate the laptop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the spaces between UUID and the mount point caused that(I used TAB spacing, dunno why). Solved.